# How to trigger Typescript type error for a function that expects some specific type and receives "any"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgqgZQCoHkCyB9ASgUQIpw7JQC8UA3gFBQ1QDOA9gLYQAKATg2AFxQBEjFgDUAhgBsArhD6UAvpUoBjBgDs6wKADMGDUlAAU7CAEde8ZOmz5CyADRQI7drwkqA1ioYB3FQEpSAHwU1LTKagxiEAB0YgwA5oYmvgDcITRhjJEx8fqO7ClyqUqq6vTMEABirorAAJaqeommsIiomLgEREj+JEFUtFDA7CDBAwMZEdGxCXwoAHJQSFgAmnwFA-LjIsCKABa5Tv79YzTaDE22eSknUAD0t4sAEgCSCFCvUCgA0mljZwfsWxGYzXE73KAAQihTw+CEeKDgABkACJQOYoJBQABCOE+X0hUN+8lkRSAA)

```
type CUSTOM_REQUEST = {
    someProp: "someValue"
}

const foo = (req: CUSTOM_REQUEST, err: unknown) => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(err);
};

const someFunction = (req: CUSTOM_REQUEST) => {
    try {
        console.log("ON TRY");
    }
    catch(err) {
        foo(req,err);       // THIS IS OK
        foo(err,req);       // !!! THIS SHOULD NOT BE OK !!!
    }
};
```

The 2nd call of `foo()` has got the parameters reversed. And no type errors are being shown.

[image]

Second argumennt should be `unknown` and `req: CUSTOM_REQUEST` is being passed. That's ok.

But first argument should be `req: CUSTOM_REQUEST` and `err:any` is being passed. That should trigger an error, right?

How can I make sure Typescript alert me of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something has type `any`, then it will never show a type error, since `any` basically disables type checking. So if you want to get a type error, then you'll need to have something other than an `any`

If you're running [typescript 4.0 or later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#unknown-on-catch), you can give the `err` variable the type `unknown` instead of `any`:

```
catch (err: unknown) {
  foo(req,err); // Still ok
  foo(err,req); // Now shows an error, as expected
}
```

If you want to make sure you always tag your errors as unknown, typescript-eslint has a rule to enforce this: [no-implicit-any-catch](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-implicit-any-catch.md)